# PHP - explain REGEX expression

Tags: php, regex

Can someone help me understand the following php regex expression. `preg_match("|store:(.*)|", $k, $matches)` In PHP regex expressions what does the '|' represent?

```
...
$storevals = array();
foreach ($item as $k => $v)
{
    if (preg_match("|store:(.*)|", $k, $matches))
    {
        $storevals[$matches[1]] = $v;
    }
}
...
```

Previous to this function is a call to convert a CSV file to an array(`$item`) with the csv headers being the keys to the array. Basically I'm trying to figure out the format for the CSV file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is pattern delimiter.

Comment: The `|` is a delimiter that marks the start and end of the regex. Any character can be used (`/` is common).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a thorough explanation -

`store:` matches the characters "store:" literally (case sensitive)
    1st capturing group `(.*)` (grouped by parentheses) `.*` matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

The pipes `|` are delimiters for the regex.

Answer (score 0):

`|` in the above code acts as a delimiter not as a part of the regex. When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters.

See more about PHP delimiters at [here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Answer (score 0):

Pipes can be used as regex delimiters, and it's your case here.

This regex is similar o :

```
/store:(.*)/
```

Which means, searching for 0+ characters following `store:`